# My paper is still with editor for about two months. Should I email the journal about that?

Tags: publications, peer-review

My paper is still with editor for about two months. My field is engineering. the paper is not controversial. It is a review article. However, the IF of the journal is high (6.7). Is it normal, or should I email the journal about that?

Comment: Did you get any feedback from the journal yet?

Comment: Yes. An email that the paper has been received by the journal, and another email that Dr "...." from editorial board is now handling the paper. Since then, I've got no emails and the article status did not change.

Comment: I assume you are not the only author? What do the other, senior collleagues say?

Answer (score 4):

The same thing happened to me. The status had not changed since the submission date. After about two months, I wrote to the editor and asked him politely to tell me if there is something wrong with my paper. Then, he responded. But, the response was nothing but just "I apologise for the delay to your paper. I have sent a reminder to the Editor to progress your paper." After three days, the paper was rejected.

So, I think: it is better to send an email to the editor and ask him to tell you the status of the manuscript. Otherwise, the status will not change (at least in the near future). Be prepared to see what I saw.